# Cannot add dynamic table inside a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create a dynamic table with the following structure:

```
# | area         | sub area    | category        | delete 
     inp. text     inp. text      table with rows   button
```

so I created the following markup:

```
 <div id="areas-container">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="add area" id="add-area">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="areas-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">
            #
          </th>
          <th class="text-center">
            area
          </th>
          <th class="text-center">
            sub area
          </th>
          <th class="text-center">
            category
          </th>
          <th class="text-center">
            delete
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id='area-0' data-id="0" class="d-none">
          <td data-name="button">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success row-addsub">sub area</button>
          </td>
          <td data-name="area" data-id="0">
            <input type="text" name='area0' data-type="area" placeholder="name" class="form-control" />
          </td>
          <td data-name="sub-area" data-id="0">
            <input type="text" name='sub_area0' data-type="sub-area" placeholder="name" class="form-control" />
          </td>
          <td data-name="category" data-id="0">
            <table class="table" name="categories-table">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>test/
                  <td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td data-name="del text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger row-remove">
              <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

now I wrote the following code for add dynamic rows to the table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#add-area').click(function() {
    let areaId = 0;
    let subAreaId = 0;
    let categoryId = 0;

    $.each($("#areas-table tr"), function() {

      // Take reference from the row
      if (parseInt($(this).data("id")) > areaId) {
        areaId = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
      }

      // Get the reference from the column
      let currSubAreaId = parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(2).data('id'));
      if (currSubAreaId > subAreaId) {
        subAreaId = currSubAreaId;
      }

      let currCatAreaId = parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(3).data('id'));
      if (currCatAreaId > categoryId) {
        subAreaId = categoryId;
      }
    });
    areaId++;
    subAreaId++;
    categoryId++;

    let tr = $("<tr></tr>", {
      id: "area-" + areaId,
      "data-id": areaId
    });

    // Clone the column
    $.each($("#areas-table tbody tr:nth(0) td"), function() {
      let curTd = $(this);
      let children = curTd.children();

      // If a name was provided, a column will be added
      if ($(this).data("name") != undefined) {
        let colName = $(curTd).data("name");
        colId = areaId; // default reference area

        switch (colName) {
          case 'sub-area':
            colId = subAreaId;
            break;
          case 'category':
            colId = categoryId;
            break;
        }

        let td = $("<td></td>", {
          "data-name": colName,
          "data-id": colId
        });

        let c = $(curTd).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("");
        c.attr("name", $(curTd).data("name") + areaId);
        c.appendTo($(td));
        td.appendTo($(tr));
      } else {
        let td = $("<td></td>", {
          'text': $('#areas-table tr').length
        }).appendTo($(tr));
      }
    });

    // add new row
    $(tr).appendTo($('#areas-table'));
  })

});
```

the problem's that the column which contains `categories-table` add an extra column to the table with an id of `3`, I suspect that the problem's related to the `.clone` method, which I used for clone the row.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#add-area').click(function() {
    let areaId = 0;
    let subAreaId = 0;
    let categoryId = 0;

    $.each($("#areas-table tr"), function() {

      // Take reference from the row
      if (parseInt($(this).data("id")) > areaId) {
        areaId = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
      }

      // Get the reference from the column
      let currSubAreaId = parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(2).data('id'));
      if (currSubAreaId > subAreaId) {
        subAreaId = currSubAreaId;
      }

      let currCatAreaId = parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(3).data('id'));
      if (currCatAreaId > categoryId) {
        subAreaId = categoryId;
      }
    });
    areaId++;
    subAreaId++;
    categoryId++;

    let tr = $("<tr></tr>", {
      id: "area-" + areaId,
      "data-id": areaId
    });

    // Clone the column
    $.each($("#areas-table tbody tr:nth(0) td"), function() {
      let curTd = $(this);
      let children = curTd.children();

      // If a name was provided, a column will be added
      if ($(this).data("name") != undefined) {
        let colName = $(curTd).data("name");
        colId = areaId; // default reference area

        switch (colName) {
          case 'sub-area':
            colId = subAreaId;
            break;
          case 'category':
            colId = categoryId;
            break;
        }

        let td = $("<td></td>", {
          "data-name": colName,
          "data-id": colId
        });

        let c = $(curTd).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("");
        c.attr("name", $(curTd).data("name") + areaId);
        c.appendTo($(td));
        td.appendTo($(tr));
      } else {
        let td = $("<td></td>", {
          'text': $('#areas-table tr').length
        }).appendTo($(tr));
      }
    });

    // add new row
    $(tr).appendTo($('#areas-table'));
  })

});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="areas-container">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="add area" id="add-area">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="areas-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">
            #
          </th>
          <th class="text-center">
            area
          </th>
          <th class="text-center">
            sub area
          </th>
          <th class="text-center">
            category
          </th>
          <th class="text-center">
            delete
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id='area-0' data-id="0" class="d-none">
          <td data-name="button">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success row-addsub">sub area</button>
          </td>
          <td data-name="area" data-id="0">
            <input type="text" name='area0' data-type="area" placeholder="name" class="form-control" />
          </td>
          <td data-name="sub-area" data-id="0">
            <input type="text" name='sub_area0' data-type="sub-area" placeholder="name" class="form-control" />
          </td>
          <td data-name="category" data-id="0">
            <table class="table" name="categories-table">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>test</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td data-name="del text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger row-remove">
              <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You hare missing a closing td, instead you have an extra opening td (in space of closing). The browser creates the closing for both hence you get an extra cell. Search for test/ in your html. the / goes inside the angle brackets.

Comment: @NawedKhan I edited the code closing the  `td` but same problem

Comment: Couple of off-topic notes (I know this isn't code review, just some minor):  `$.each($("#areas-table tr")` could be `$("#areas-table tr").each(` / `$("<tr></td>")` can be just `$("<td>")` / no need for parseInt if using `.data("intattr")` as jquery converts it to an int for you.

Comment: `subAreaId = categoryId` should probably be `categoryId = currCatAreaId`

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks I didn't noticed this, there was the problem

Comment: It might affect 2nd+ rows, but you can remove that whole section of code for the first click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your selector `$.each($("#areas-table tbody tr:nth(0) td"), ...` to  `$.each($("#areas-table tbody tr:nth(0)>td"), ...` so that you only select the direct descendants of the parent tr element and not the nested table cells.

**EDIT**

> I get the same problem, did you actually tried your solution?

... Thats how its intend to work right? no extra column?!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#add-area').click(function() {
    let areaId = 0;
    let subAreaId = 0;
    let categoryId = 0;

    $.each($("#areas-table tr"), function() {

      // Take reference from the row
      if (parseInt($(this).data("id")) > areaId) {
        areaId = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
      }

      // Get the reference from the column
      let currSubAreaId = parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(2).data('id'));
      if (currSubAreaId > subAreaId) {
        subAreaId = currSubAreaId;
      }

      let currCatAreaId = parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(3).data('id'));
      if (currCatAreaId > categoryId) {
        subAreaId = categoryId;
      }
    });
    areaId++;
    subAreaId++;
    categoryId++;

    let tr = $("<tr></tr>", {
      id: "area-" + areaId,
      "data-id": areaId
    });

    // Clone the column
    $.each($("#areas-table tbody tr:nth(0)>td"), function() {
      let curTd = $(this);
      let children = curTd.children();

      // If a name was provided, a column will be added
      if ($(this).data("name") != undefined) {
        let colName = $(curTd).data("name");
        colId = areaId; // default reference area

        switch (colName) {
          case 'sub-area':
            colId = subAreaId;
            break;
          case 'category':
            colId = categoryId;
            break;
        }

        let td = $("<td></td>", {
          "data-name": colName,
          "data-id": colId
        });

        let c = $(curTd).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("");
        c.attr("name", $(curTd).data("name") + areaId);
        c.appendTo($(td));
        td.appendTo($(tr));
      } else {
        let td = $("<td></td>", {
          'text': $('#areas-table tr').length
        }).appendTo($(tr));
      }
    });

    // add new row
    $(tr).appendTo($('#areas-table'));
  })

});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="areas-container">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="add area" id="add-area">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="areas-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">
            #
          </th>
          <th class="text-center">
            area
          </th>
          <th class="text-center">
            sub area
          </th>
          <th class="text-center">
            category
          </th>
          <th class="text-center">
            delete
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id='area-0' data-id="0" class="d-none">
          <td data-name="button">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success row-addsub">sub area</button>
          </td>
          <td data-name="area" data-id="0">
            <input type="text" name='area0' data-type="area" placeholder="name" class="form-control" />
          </td>
          <td data-name="sub-area" data-id="0">
            <input type="text" name='sub_area0' data-type="sub-area" placeholder="name" class="form-control" />
          </td>
          <td data-name="category" data-id="0">
            <table class="table" name="categories-table">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>test</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td data-name="del text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger row-remove">
              <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get the same problem, did you actually tried your solution?

Comment: *"did you actually try your solution"* - yes.  I just copied the snippet into an answer, ran it, gave extra column 3 - changed the selector to add `>td` ran it and no extra column.  **edit:** snippet added above by Mischa

Comment: Yes, sorry, for some reason ftp isn't worked. Thank you very much :)